# Filter Out Element from Nested Array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, sorting

```
let input array=[["1.81","2.24"],["5.62","6.26"],false,["2.31","1.64"],false,false]

let output array=[["1.81","2.24"],["5.62","6.26"],["2.31","1.64"]];
```

[image]

I have a nested input array which contains smaller arrays and false statement as shown in the console. How do I remove the false statement from the input array?  I have tried using for loop to loop through all the 6 elements to check each element with a (if !==false), then **push** into a new array called the output array but I could not get it to work? May I know how to solve this? Your help will be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Directly use `Array#filter`:

```js
let input=[["1.81","2.24"],["5.62","6.26"],false,["2.31","1.64"],false,false]
let res = input.filter(Boolean);
console.log(res);
```